# eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix are always orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

As we know by the famous theorem "eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal for a real symmetric matrix"
can this result be also true for the same eigenvalues
My intuition says yes.
i.e.
for a real symmetric matrix eigenvectors are orthogonal whether the eigenvalue is distinct or the same.
Note we have one counter-example for if the matrix is not real Symmetrix then eigenvectors are not orthogonal if the eigenvalues are the same.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i \\
i & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
but in real case I'm confused,
so solution is appearsiable.

Comment: If $A=I$ then $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ are both eigenvectors...

Comment: Do not confuse if eigenvectors *must* be orthogonal and if they *can be chosen* to be orthogonal. All nonzero vectors in $\mathbf R^2$ are eigenvectors of the identity matrix but they are not all orthogonal.

Comment: If an eigenvalue of a real symmetric matrix has multiplicity $k$ , then we can find $k$ pairwise orthogonal eigenvectors corresponding with this eigenvalue.

Comment: $v$ and $2v$ are eigenvectors for $\lambda$ as soon as $v$ is.

Comment: @KCd means all eigenvectors space may not be orthogonal for the real symmetric matrix but we can choose some orthogonal eigenvectors space. right sir

Answer (score 5):

If an eigenspace has dimension $>1$, then *any* basis of that subspace consists of eigenvectors. Clearly, these *can* be picked to be orthogonal, but they *need not* be orthogonal.

Comment: okay I understand thank you, sir